# Customize header in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

in my app home screen I want to custom the header to have two icons in left and right which can be done using:

```
<HomeStack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        title: '',    
        headerLeft: () => (
          <View style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
            <Icon.Button
              name="ios-menu"
              size={25}
              color="#000000"
              backgroundColor={COLORS.primary}
              onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            />
          </View>
        ),
        
        headerRight: () => (
          <View style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
            <Icon.Button
              name="location-outline"
              size={25}
              color="#000000"
              backgroundColor={COLORS.primary}
              onPress={() => navigation.openMap()}
            />
          </View>
        ),
 }} />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
```

I want to add additional  but to be in the center which will be customized based on my needs, but I have no idea how to implement that as there is nothing called  headerCneter:

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can take advantage of the [header](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#header) option inside the stack navigator? You can then use the route params to customize your header from there.

Comment: but route params used to pass params, but me for example if want to add search bar in the center of header and two icon in right in left, can you give a simple example  fot that?

Comment: Yes, the header is just a React Element. You can create your own search bar view and add your logic to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass react component in headerTitle:

```
 <HomeStack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        headerTitle: () => {
          return (
            <View style={st.horizontalRow}>
              <LeftIcon />
              <TextInput
                placeholder="search"
              />
              <RightIcon />
            </View>
          );
        },
        headerTitleAlign: 'left',
        headerTitleContainerStyle: {
          left: 40,
          right: 0,
        },
 }} />
```